# Is there any way I can generate the following series?

Tags: c++

Consider the following series `sk=s(k-1)(!s(k-1))(!s(k-1))s(k-1)`. Take `s1=1221` and `!s1=2112`, therefore `s2=s1(!s1)(!s1)s1`, which means `s2=1221211221121221`.

My current goal is to generate n elements of this series and then to determine the n-th element. I'm sorry if I made the question sound complicated.

I tried making this work but the code just doesn't show the correct answer or it doesn't work at all. I'd hope to see another perspective on this problem.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,k=1,a,b,s=1,p=1,i=1;
    a=1;b=2;
    cin>>n;
    while(i<=n){
        if(s==1){
            if(k==1){
                cout<<a;
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else{if(k==2||k==3){
                cout<<b;
                i++;
                k++;
            }
                if(k==4){
                    cout<<a<<" ";
                    i++;
                    k=1;p++;
                    if(p==2) {s=2;p=0;}
                }
        }}
        if(i<=n){
        if(s==2){
            if(k==1){
                cout<<b;
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else{if(k==2||k==3){
                cout<<a;
                i++;
                k++;
            }
                if(k==4){
                    cout<<b<<" ";
                    i++;
                    k=1;p++;
                    if(p==2) {s=1;p=0;}
                }
        }
    }
    }}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, there are multiple ways to approach problems such as yours. Try to ask a specific question and do read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. If you have trouble with your implementation you should post your code, your input and the expected output.

Comment: i posted the code

Comment: What are the basic elements? Only 1 and 2. In another way, what can the value of s0 be?

Comment: there's no s0. s1 is the first element in the sequence. And yes just 1 and 2

Comment: @pelikanByu [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution for your sequence generator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// generate inverted term s -> !s
std::string invert(const std::string& s) {
    const char a = '1';
    const char b = '2';
    std::string out;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        // here one can check for invalid input as well, eg 0
        out += s[i] == a ? b : a;
    }
    return out;
}

// sk = s(k - 1)(!s(k - 1))(!s(k - 1))s(k - 1)
std::string nextSeq(const std::string& s) {
    std::string s_inv = invert(s);
    return s + s_inv + s_inv + s;
}

// generate nth term of the sequence.
std::string nthSeq(const std::string& s, const int n) {
    std::string out = s;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        out = nextSeq(out);
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "1221";
    // this will 2nd term 1221211221121221
    std::cout << nthSeq(s1, 2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```